# Is there a way to disable console.log in specified component or file?(Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript, console

I know we can use

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  if(window){
    window.console.log=function(){};
  }
}
```

to control the console in the whole project. but what if I only want to disable console in a specified component or file?

is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is the exact use case for this? Wouldn't it be as simple as not called the console.log for that specific component.

Another option would be to create a LogService, in which you pass the log message and the source. And then inside the service check whether the source matches a list of your blacklisted sources.

Comment: @Jelle I'm developing with other developers , and sometimes they feel annoying  with my logs , but it could be cumbersome remove console one by one , so I want to disable console just in my part of the code. (by giving a property or something else)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own logger service and write a function in it. Let's say `loggerService`

```
//Declare a boolean variable     
print = true

//call the console function in your component
this.loggerService.console(print, "console your message" );
```

In the service you can implement your own console function, which prints message to window console

This is one of the method, we created this method in our project to send client specific errors to analytics server